# Sequelize call structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, sequelize.js

I'm working with sequelize and want to query my database using the following code:

```
models.user.findOne({ where: {email: req.body.email} }, (err, existingUser) => {
.... More code
}
```

But the code block wont run so i read the docs and the only example they give uses the following structure:

```
models.user.findOne({ where: {title: 'aProject'} }).then(project => {
.... Code
})
```

Did i do something wrong with the first example or am i just unable to use that structure?

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize.js uses promises. When you use `findOne`, as an example, a `promise` is returned. So try the following:

```
models.user.findOne({ 
    where: {
        email: req.body.email
    }).then(existingUser => {
       //Do something
    }).catch(err => {
       //Do something with error
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize>=1.7 query return a promise , to resolve it you need to use "then"

nb: you can use the model directly from the declaration instead of "models.user" like this:

```
const Userdb = sequelize.define('userdb', {
 id : {
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement:true,
  allowNull:false,
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
  email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull:false,
  validation:{
   isEmail:true
  },

username: {
  type:  Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull:false,
  min:6,
  max:25,
  notEmpty:true,
}
}
```

and to get a user by it's email you can do this :

```
Userdb.findOne({
            where: { 
                    email: req.body.email
                   }
               }).then((result)=>{
                   if(results) // there is one user 
                      {
                    // do something with resutls 
                      }else{
                        // no user with that mail 
                        }
                      })
```